# $(document).ready listeners not running on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, action, listener

I have a `$(document).ready` function that sets up listeners for certain elements.  However, all of the `#leave-ride` elements are added dynamically.

Listeners:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#post-ride").click(function() {
        addRide(currentDriver, $(destinationInput).val(), $(originInput).val(), $(dateInput).val(), $(timeInput).val());
        $.getScript("scripts/myRides.js", function() {});
    });

    $("#request-ride").click(function() {
        requestRide(currentDriver, $(destinationInput).val(), $(originInput).val(), $(dateInput).val(), $(timeInput).val());
        $.getScript("scripts/myRides.js", function() {});
    });

    $("#leave-ride").click(function() {
        console.log("leave Ride");
        leaveRide(currentDriver, $("leave-ride").closest("div").attr("id"));
        $.getScript("scripts/myRides.js", function() {});
    });
});
```

What do I need to do to get that listener to listen to dynamic content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript event loading w/dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163637/javascript-event-loading-w-dynamic-content)

Comment: An id should only be used once in your document, and `$('leave-ride')` is most likely going to be empty.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `ready` runs only once. You can use event delegation:

Take the element closest to the `#leave-ride` which is not loaded dynamically (`document` in extreme cases). Then attach the handler on it, and use `#leave-ride` as the selector for the [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Assuming a div having the id `#container` is that static element:

```
$('div#container').on('click', '#leave-ride', function(){…});
```

See also [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/1048572)

Comment: +1 using a container will be more efficient than applying on() to the whole document.

Answer (score 3):

Use `on`, change your event declaration

```
$("#post-ride").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("body").on('click',"#post-ride",(function() {
```

Comment: $(document)  without quotes

Comment: @roasted - yup :) usually I use "body" there so that is where the quotes came from, I will change it to body.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()`

Example:

```
$("#leave-ride").on('click', function() {
   console.log("leave Ride");
   leaveRide(currentDriver, $("leave-ride").closest("div").attr("id"));
   $.getScript("scripts/myRides.js", function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: That won't make any difference.  You need to pass a selector.

Comment: You are not using delegation here

Comment: `on` has some differences to `live`, one of them is that you need to delegate the event out.